# Does load balancing pose extra security risks?

Tags: web-application

If I'd have a basic Laravel back-end application I'd configure my load balancing using Nginx. I would have one server with the sole purpose of load balancing. The other servers would contain my Laravel-code and the configuration for SSL etc.

But doesn't this architecture pose extra security concerns? Having multiple servers with the same code has the risk of having a server with a wrong security configuration or a unpatched bug in the code.

Comment: That's why you use the same code and configs on all systems and use all those free tools to apply that code and configs across the environment....

Comment: "Availability" is part of the triad.